# UDF that accepts one parameter and returns a table

Tags: sql, user-defined-functions

Question: Create a UDF that accepts the State Province and returns the associated Sales Tax Rate, StateProvinceCode and CountryRegionCode (Database is AdventureWorks2012)

Name took the place of State Province because there is no column
called 'State Province', and 'Name' contains the needed information.
This is what I did in the code below.

Is there another way to run this?
In this form Ambiguous column name keeps showing up.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fx_TxSpCr  (@Name Nvarchar(50), 
                            @TaxRate Smallmoney,
                            @StateProvinceCode Nchar(3),
                            @CountryRegionCode Nvarchar(3)
                            )
RETURNS TABLE
AS  
RETURN  (
            SELECT  Name,TaxRate,StateProvinceCode,CountryRegionCode
            FROM    Sales.SalesTaxRate s
            JOIN    Person.StateProvince t
            ON      s.StateProvinceID=t.StateProvinceID
            JOIN    Sales.SalesTerritory u
            ON      t.TerritoryID=u.TerritoryID
            )

SELECT      s.TaxRate,t.StateProvinceCode,u.CountryRegionCode
FROM        fx_TxSpCr
GROUP BY    Name
```

Comment: Thanks JNeil.  I ran the code according to your edit and it worked. However, when I ran the following query (with a name ie State Province, it produced an error code - Parameters were not supplied for the function 'fx_TxSpC.  So I am reading up on it to see what goes where                SELECT  s.TaxRate,t.StateProvinceCode,u.CountryRegionCode
FROM  fx_TxSpC
WHERE  Name='Idaho'

Comment: Ran this code based on the suggestion of both you and Lance jt. (SELECT  t.Name,s.TaxRate,t.StateProvinceCode,u.CountryRegionCode
            FROM    Sales.SalesTaxRate s
            JOIN    Person.StateProvince t
            ON      s.StateProvinceID=t.StateProvinceID
            JOIN    Sales.SalesTerritory u
            ON      t.TerritoryID=u.TerritoryID
   WHERE t.Name = @Name
   AND  s.TaxRate=@TaxRate
   AND  t.StateProvinceCode=@StateProvinceCode
   AND  u.CountryRegionCode=@CountryRegionCode
            )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you both for the contribution. This worked:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fx_TaxStCtry(@StateProvince nvarchar(50)) 
RETURNS @TaxStCtry TABLE 
(TaxRate SmallMoney not null,
StateProvinceCode Nchar(3) not null ,
CountryRegionCode Nvarchar(3) not null) 
AS 
BEGIN INSERT @TaxStCtry 
SELECT  tr.TaxRat,sp.StateProvinceCode,sp.CountryRegionCode
FROM Person.StateProvince sp 
JOIN   Sales.SalesTaxRate tr 
ON tr.stateprovinceid = sp.stateprovinceid
WHERE   sp.Name=@StateProvince 
RETURN 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The ambiguity is coming from the lack of aliases in the select statement from your function. It seems like you are trying to use the aliases in the execution of the function, but they actually need to be contained within the function itself. (For example, all three tables have a "name" column.)

After correcting that issue you will find that you actually have not used any of the parameters you have set up for your function. Which does not have to be the full return set of the select statement contained within.

The correct path here is to start with a **select** statement that returns what you're needing and then turn that into a function. If the data is not being returned at a base level, then you're not ready to start creating a function.

Comment: THANK YOU Lancet RETURNS TABLE
AS  
RETURN  (SELECT  t.Name,s.TaxRate,t.StateProvinceCode,u.CountryRegionCode
            FROM    Sales.SalesTaxRate s
            JOIN    Person.StateProvince t
            ON      s.StateProvinceID=t.StateProvinceID
            JOIN    Sales.SalesTerritory u
            ON      t.TerritoryID=u.TerritoryID
            )
Alright. I ran it with the columns as shown above. It worked the same as before. And the query below resulted  in the same error message. SELECT      s.TaxRate,t.StateProvinceCode,u.CountryRegionCode
FROM        fx_TxSpC
WHERE t.Name = Idaho

Comment: The next step would be to move the **where** statement into the function. You also do not have to use the aliases when calling the function. Finally, when calling the function you would use the syntax SELECT [Columns] from fx_TxSpC ('Idaho').